# Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat → Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun

Tags: wordpress, fullcalendar

I have purchased a Theme in wp that is using https://fullcalendar.io/

Current Week Structure is → **Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat**, but 
I want it to be like → **Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat Sun**

This is the theme Demo from where I have purchased [Click Here →](http://demo2.blogeto.com/benedicto/church/)

The theme owner aid contact to https://fullcalendar.io/, but on their website I find that I have to seek StackOverflow for the support.

Comment: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/

Comment: I have already browsed that forum, but i can't understand where should I go to make that change I mean in which file?

Comment: You'll have to find the code part where the fullcalendar script gets configured/initialized. (Unless the theme/plugin offers any kind of configuration in that regard via the backend.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have to make a change to the javascript of the theme to accomplish this. Check out the file `events.js` in the `js` directory of your theme. Starting on line `48` try replacing this code:

```
jQuery('#event-calender-widget').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio:1,
    events: calenderAjax.events,
```

With:

```
jQuery('#event-calender-widget').fullCalendar({
    aspectRatio:1,
    firstDay:1,
    events: calenderAjax.events,
```

Good luck!

Comment: I have literally no words to thank you. I am a beginner in programming so hardly understand the documentations. I was struggling from last 3 days to sort this. when I posted the question I was Voted down despite the fact that my question was 100% genuine. It looks like they respect Pro's, in that case, they should mention that this community is not for a person like me who are not Pros, but beginners. Thanks again.

Comment: I have made the changes in events.js, but when I update events.js changes will be lost. Is there any method by which I cam make such changes in functions.php of Wordpress so that in future when events.js is updated the changes are not lost. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad to hear I could be of any help. It looks like the calendar settings cannot be updated after it has been rendered. To prevent your changes from being overridden you could consider creating a child theme and recreate your events.js file there with the updated code. More information about child themes can be found here: https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes. This is usually the way to go when overriding settings from a theme. It might take a bit of work depending on your theme and you still have to check for updates to events.js. Good luck and have a good day!

Answer (score 0):

you may take a look at [firstDay](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/display/firstDay/) option of full calendar